# show/hide the corresponding part content of li?

Tags: jquery

the hmtl code:

```
  <div id="nav">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">test 2</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
  <p> <a href="#">link </a>  <a href="#">link </a> <a href="#">link </a>  </p>
  </div>

  </li>
 <li><a href="#">test 3</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
  <p> <a href="#">link2 </a>  <a href="#">link3</a> <a href="#">link4 </a>  </p>
  </div>

</li>
 <li><a href="#">test 4</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

i want to do when the mouse hover on the **li**, it will show the  corresponding part content(`sub-nav`). when the mouse move off the li, the  corresponding part will be hidden.

```
.sub-menu css is display:none;
```

the following is my code, but doesn't work.

```
$(function(){

    $("#nav ul li").mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).find(".sub-menu").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: your class name in html is `sub-nav` not `sub-menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have `.sub-menu` class in CSS and JavaScript but `.sub-nav` in the markup.

Here is the working solution:

```
$("#nav ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".sub-nav").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".sub-nav").hide();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/e8GYJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#nav ul li").mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).find(".sub-menu").show();
    }.mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).find(".sub-menu").hide();
    });
```

check out this code...

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try the `hover()` event callback : http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

try to user [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function:

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
     $(this).find(".sub-menu").show();
  }, 
  function () {
     $(this).find(".sub-menu").hide();
  }
);
```